# how to change WebView content font-family via javascript in android?

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

My android application has a setting screen in which users may select a custom font and have it applied everywhere, All fonts are saved in res/font directory ... My problem is that once a font is selected, it is applied to the whole project except for **html** files as they are styled by a **css** file.

User selects a font using this screen and changes takes effect immediately as shown below:
[image]

I would like to apply user's font to my html files ... this is how they look now :(
[image]

I think this may be achieved by changing the font-family in the css file .. 
here is my css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
} 
h3 {
  color:  blue;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
} 
h4 {
  color:  blue;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
} 
p {
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
ul {
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
ol {
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
a:link {
     color:  blue;
     font-size:16px;
     text-decoration: underline;
     text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
 }
 a:visited {
     color:  blue;
     font-size:16px;
     text-decoration: underline;
     text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
 }
  a:active {
      color:  blue;
      font-size:16px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-align: justify;
      margin: 10px;
  }
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
h3 {
  color:  blue;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
h4 {
  color:  blue;
  font-size:23px;
  text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
p {
    font-size:23px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
ul {
    font-size:23px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
ol {
    font-size:23px;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
     margin: 10px;
}
a:link {
     color:  blue;
     font-size:23px;
     text-decoration: underline;
     text-align: justify;
      margin: 10px;
 }
 a:visited {
     color:  blue;
     font-size:23px;
     text-decoration: underline;
     text-align: justify;
      margin: 10px;
 }
  a:active {
      color:  blue;
      font-size:23px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-align: justify;
       margin: 10px;
  }
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
}
```

How is this done ??

Comment: do you use webView ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change your HTML files font-family directly via android .
Your problem will be solved by JavaScript .
Followed My Approach:

**First :)** define your custome font in your **CSS** file as bleow using @font-face

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourfontName1';
    src: url('android.resource://yourAppPackageName/font/yourfontName1.fontFromat');
    /* font format can be ttf , otf and ...*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yourfontName2';
    src: url('android.resource://yourAppPackageName/font/yourfontName2.fontFormat');
        /* font format can be ttf , otf and ...*/

}
/* other font definition */
```

**Second :)** 
Change `domStorageEnabled` form false (default value) to **true** ,enable **JavaScript** for your WebView and **disable** caching

```
mWebview.getSetting().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

**Third :)**

Run a **JavaScript function** by your WebView  in your **onItemSelectedListener** or what ever you want:

```
String script= "javascript:(function(){  " +
                        "var cols = document.getElementsByTagName('*');" +
                        "for(i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {" +
                        "cols[i].style[\"font-family\"]=\""+yourSelectedFontName+"\";" +
                        "}})();";

mWebview.evaluateJavascript(script,null);
```

This worked for me and I hope it works for you too **:)**

Comment: Thank you Alireza Bideli for your reply, I have tried it but it did't work.

Comment: I have updated with my question after implementing Alireza Bideli solution.

Comment: loadWebView(); is called onCreate

Comment: is "www.alitkaan3.com" your application packageName ?

Comment: I did not select the page to be loaded and that is why it is empty ... I have tried adding  mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + pageTitle + ".html"); after mywebView.evaluateJavascript(script,null); and the page loaded with original font

Comment: src: url('android.resource://www.alitkaan3.com/font/hacen.ttf');is this correct ?

Comment: it worked after adding this to css file: body {
  font-family: aljazeera;
}

Answer (score 1):

It worked ... This is what I have done

**Added to CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: aljazeera;
     src: url("file:///android_res/font/aljazeera.ttf")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: barada;
    src: url('file:///android_res/font//barada.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: hacen;
    src: url('file:///android_res/font//hacen.ttf');
}

body {
  font-family: aljazeera;
}
```

**Added this class to activity** FontStyle is based on user preference

```
public class JavaScriptWebViewClient extends WebViewClient    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            shared = getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int selectedFont = shared.getInt("myFont", 4);
            String FontStyle = "sans-serif";


            switch (selectedFont){
                case 1:
                    FontStyle ="sans-serif";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    FontStyle ="hacen";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    FontStyle ="aljazeera";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    FontStyle ="barada";
                    break;
            }

            String script= "javascript:(function(){  " +
                    "var cols = document.getElementsByTagName('*');" +
                    "for(i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {" +
                    "cols[i].style[\"font-family\"]=\""+FontStyle+"\";" +
                    "}})();";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                view.evaluateJavascript(script,null);
            }else {
                view.loadUrl(script);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Added loadWebView** which is called onCreate

```
 private void loadWebView() {
        Intent data = getIntent();
        String pageTitle = data.getStringExtra("pageTitle");


        title.setText(pageTitle);

        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new JavaScriptWebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + pageTitle + ".html");

    }
```

Comment: I test my answer. My solution only worked when your webview  have loaded before and you want to change the webView font with an event like button onClick

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer that works like a sharme

**CSS**
add variables under (:root) as required, add (@font-face) as required, Assign variables to tags

```
:root {
--myFont: 'aaagolden';
--myColor: #A21719;
--myColorB: #FFE1E1;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'aaagolden';
src: url('file:///android_res/font/aaagolden.ttf');
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
font-family: var(--myFont);
color:  var(--myColor);
text-align: justify;
margin: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript Interface** create JSInterface class containing methods to get font and colors from shared preference and store them in strings

```
public class JSInterface {

    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences shared;

    public JSInterface(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast (String msg){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getMyFont (){
        String myFont = "barada";
        shared = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int selectedFont = shared.getInt("myFont", 4);

        switch (selectedFont) {
            case 1:
                myFont ="aaagolden";
                break;
            case 2:
                myFont ="hacen";
                break;
            case 3:
                myFont ="aljazeera";
                break;
            case 4:
                myFont ="barada";
                break;
            case 5:
                myFont ="times";
                break;
            case 6:
                myFont ="calibri";
                break;
        }
        return myFont;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getMyColor (){
        String myColor ="#1565C0";
        shared = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int selectedTheme = shared.getInt("myStyle", 30);

        switch (selectedTheme) {
            case 10:
                myColor ="008577";
                break;
            case 20:
                myColor ="C51A1C";
                break;
            case 30:
                myColor ="1565C0";
                break;
            case 40:
                myColor ="8B7969";
                break;
            case 50:
                myColor ="6f2699";
                break;
            case 60:
                myColor ="A73A13";
                break;
        }
        return myColor;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getMyColorB (){
        String myColorB ="A4D9F8";
        shared = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int selectedTheme = shared.getInt("myStyle", 30);

        switch (selectedTheme) {
            case 10:
                myColorB ="8AF3E1";
                break;
            case 20:
                myColorB ="FFE1E1";
                break;
            case 30:
                myColorB ="A4D9F8";
                break;
            case 40:
                myColorB ="DFC2AF";
                break;
            case 50:
                myColorB ="C39DE2";
                break;
            case 60:
                myColorB ="FCC1AC";
                break;
        }
        return myColorB;
    }

}
```

**Webview Activity**  addJavascriptInterface using JSInterface class to webview named AndroidFunction

```
WebView mywebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
mywebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Intent data = getIntent();
if(data.getExtras() != null){
    Utils.CustomToast(ViewActivity.this,"جاري التحميل ...");
    pageTitle = data.getStringExtra("pageTitle");
} else{
    pageTitle = "القرءان الكريم";
}
actionBar.setTitle(pageTitle);
// the name of the interface (AndroidFunction) will be used later so remember it
mywebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this),"AndroidFunction"); 
mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + pageTitle + ".html");
```

**HTML**
in the head section: link style sheet, add variables defined in under styles>:root, add javascript calling the methods created in JSInterface named AndroidFunction

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/stylesheet.css" />
    <style>
        :root {
            --myFont: 'aaagolden';
            --myColor: #A21719;
            --myColorB: #FFE1E1; 
            }
    </style>
    <script>
         var font = AndroidFunction.getMyFont();
         var color = AndroidFunction.getMyColor();
         var colorB = AndroidFunction.getMyColorB();

         var r = document.querySelector(':root');
          r.style.setProperty('--myFont', font);
          r.style.setProperty('--myColor', '#' + color);
          r.style.setProperty('--myColorB', '#' + colorB);
    </script>
</head>
```

**It took me moths to figure this out (Not enough information on the internet) ... I hope you find this useful**